# sort an array by row in python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I understood that sorting a numpy array `arr` by column (for only a particular column, for example, its 2nd column) can be done with:

```
arr[arr[:,1].argsort()]
```

How I understood this code sample works: `argsort` sorts the values of the 2nd column of `arr`, and gives the corresponding indices as an array. This array is given to `arr` as row numbers. Am I correct in my interpretation?

Now I wonder what if I want to sort the array `arr` with respect to the 2nd row instead of the 2nd column? Is the simplest way to transpose the array before sorting it and transpose it back after sorting, or is there a way to do it like previously (by giving an array with the number of the columns we wish to display)?

Instead of doing `(n,n)array[(n,)array]` (n is the size of the 2d array) I tried to do something like `(n,n)array[(n,1)array]` to indicate the numbers of the columns but it does not work.

EXAMPLE of what I want:

`arr = [[11,25],[33,4]]` => base array

`arr_col2=[[33,4],[11,25]]` => array I got with `argsort()`

`arr_row2=[[25,11],[4,33]]` => array I tried to got in a simple way with `argsort()` but did not succeed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sort 2d array by row in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173797/how-to-sort-2d-array-by-row-in-python)

Comment: I suspect that this is a numpy array, not a vanilla python array - in which case it's not a duplicate of that question (though probably has been asked elsewhere anyway)

Comment: It is not a duplicate indeed. What I want is to know if there is a similar way to the method I described to sort a numpy array wrt a particular row, without mixing the columns (instead of sorting wrt to a column). The main thing I dont get is how 2darray[1darray] works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `arr` is a numpy array? I haven't seen the syntax `arr[:,1]` in any other context in python. It would be worth mentioning this in your question!

Assuming this is the case, then you should be using

```
arr.sort(axis=0)
```

to sort by column and

```
arr.sort(axis=1)
```

to sort by row. (Both sort in-place, *i.e.* change the value of `arr`. If you don't want this you can copy `arr` into another variable first, and apply `sort` to that.)

If you want to sort just a single row (in this case, the second one) then

```
arr[1,:].sort()
```

works.

**Edit:** I now understand what problem you are trying to solve. You would like to reorder the columns in the matrix so that the n<sup>th</sup> row goes in increasing order. You can do this simply by

```
arr[:,arr[1,:].argsort()]
```

(where here we're sorting by the 2nd row).

Comment: You assumed correctly =).
However I tried to sort the way you are telling before using the method I described (seemed more logical...), but it sorts all the rows or all the columns, whereas I want to only sort one particular column whithout mixing the rows. And I wanted to know if there was a way to sort one particular row the same way with argsort

Comment: I've updated my answer to answer that - again I still don't think argsort is the way to go!

Comment: Then again it is not what I want, since I want the rows to remain the same. By doing `arr[1,:].sort()` the column 2 is sorted but the column 1 is not, which causes the rows to be mixed up compared to the unsorted array. Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: Sorry, could you give me an example of a (say) 3x3 matrix as input and the output you're looking for?

Comment: Ok I should have begun by this. I edited the first post with an example

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for, thanks ! But for your edit to be correct it should be `arr[:,arr[1,:].argsort()]` instead of `arr[:,arr[:,1].argsort()]`, I think