# Sort Python Columns with corresponding rows

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

I want to sort column values depending on a row full of int:

```
cart = [[1, 3, 0, 2], ['olives', 'tomatoes', 'avocado', 'patato']]
```

and have this

```
new_cart= [[0, 1, 2, 3], ['avocado', 'olives', 'patato', 'tomatoes' ]]
```

In other words I want strings to sorted by the integers values which they corresponds:

I found these questions but non of them does what I want:

[how to sort 2d array by row in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173797/how-to-sort-2d-array-by-row-in-python)

[How to sort multidimensional array by column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183069/how-to-sort-multidimensional-array-by-column#comment30091385_20183069)

Comment: What is the order rule for the second sub-list? It looks like it is in alphabetical order. Are you pretty much just looking to sort in increasing order?

Comment: no integer ordeer let me change it.

Comment: You are sorting the inner lists too? ...Dear?

Comment: I edited, as you can see depending on first list with integers, I want to sort strings too as you can see

Comment: As far as I understood your question, you want to sort it like this:

    a = np.array([[1, 3, 0], ['olives', 'tomatoes', 'avocado']])
    a.sort()

Comment: @RameshKumar You are assuming that numpy is being used here. There is no indication that numpy is being used, and I'm assuming you are using numpy because of the np reference. That is not so easy to decipher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A zip-sort-unzip procedure should do the trick:

```
data = [[1, 3, 0, 2], ['olives', 'tomatoes', 'avocado', 'patato']]
sorted_data = zip(*sorted(zip(data[0], data[1])))
# [(0, 1, 2, 3), ('avocado', 'olives', 'patato', 'tomatoes')]
```

Or if you want to keep them as lists:

```
sorted_data = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(data[0], data[1]))))
# [[0, 1, 2, 3], ['avocado', 'olives', 'patato', 'tomatoes']]
```

On Python 3.x both `zip` and `map` return iterators so if you want to 'bake' them into lists just 'cast' them as such, i.e.:

```
sorted_data = list(map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(data[0], data[1])))))
```

NOTE: As suggested by JJoao, you can use argument expansion in the inner `zip` too instead of explicitly selecting which fields you want to `zip` from your list, e.g.:

```
sorted_data = list(map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(*data)))))
```

Comment: why I cannot print it? <map object at 0x02CE7730> this is output

Comment: @RonnieJamesDio - because you're using Python 3.x and its `map` returns an iterator. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @RonnieJamesDio If the solutions you looked at used `zip`, you probably had your answer all along. Check the documentation on [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip). Also, the second part of the solution shows how to end up with a *list*. The *map* object you are looking at is an *iterator*.

Comment: I need to end up with a list.

Comment: thank you, I coudnt find a question like mine in the stackoverflow, do you think I can get a vote up :))

Comment: @JJoao - fair point, I wanted to keep literal so that the user knows what field its sorted on first. I'll add a note.

Comment: @zwer: very reasonable decision - expanded version is more didactic.

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted_data=[ sorted(i) for i in data ]
# [[0, 1, 2, 3], ['avocado', 'olives', 'patato', 'tomatoes']]
```

This will do the trick. Simple list comprehension .!