# Get the first three largest values of a 2dnumpy array in python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy-ndarray

Hi I have a numpy array for eg.

```
arr = np.random.rand(4,5)

array([[0.70733982, 0.1770464 , 0.55588376, 0.8810145 , 0.43711158],
       [0.22056565, 0.0193138 , 0.89995761, 0.75157581, 0.21073093],
       [0.22333035, 0.92795789, 0.3903581 , 0.41225472, 0.74992639],
       [0.92328687, 0.20438876, 0.63975818, 0.6179422 , 0.40596821]])
```

I need to find the first three largest elements in the array.I tried

```
arr[[-arr.argsort(axis=-1)[:, :3]]]
```

I also referred this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-do-i-get-indices-of-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array/23734295#23734295) on StackOverflow which only gives indices not values

I was able to get the indices of the first three max values,but how to get its corresponding values.?

Also I tried sorting the array by converting into list like given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173797/how-to-sort-2d-array-by-row-in-python)

But didnt give me the required result.Any Ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get indices of N maximum values in a NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-do-i-get-indices-of-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array)

Comment: I referred that question sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use `np.sort()`:

```
# np.sort sorts in ascending order
# --> we apply np.sort -arr
arr_sorted = -np.sort(-arr,axis=1)
top_three = arr_sorted[:,:3]
```

Comment: Sorry I need first 3 values from each row of numpy array

Comment: Just wanted to know waht does '-' do here? and is there a way if its list of lists?

Comment: By default, np.sort sorts in ascending order. By reversing the sign in sort, you get the descending order. Then ,you get the right order, but with all negative numbers. So you need to revert the sign back. If you have a list of lists, you could just convert to numpy and do the same

Comment: You can avoid the negative sign by just `top_three = np.sort(arr, axis=1)[:, -3:]`

Answer (score 1):

This question already has a valid accepted answer, but I just wanted to point out that using [`np.partition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) instead of [`np.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) will be much faster in the case of a larger array. We do still use `np.sort`, but only on the small subset of the array that makes up our row-wise top threes.

```
arr = np.random.random((10000, 10000))
top_three_fast = np.sort(np.partition(arr, -3)[:, -3:])[:, ::-1]
```

Timings:

```
In [22]: %timeit top_three_fast = np.sort(np.partition(arr, -3)[:, -3:])[:, ::-1]
1.04 s ± 8.43 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [23]: %timeit top_three_slow = -np.sort(-arr, axis=1)[:, :3]
6.22 s ± 111 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [24]: (top_three_slow == top_three_fast).all()
Out[24]: True
```