# How to sort numpy array column-wise consequetly?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I want to sort 2d array column-wise consequently, so if the values in one column are equal then sorting is performed by next column.
For example array

```
[[1, 0, 4, 2, 3]
 [0, 1, 5, 7, 4]
 [0, 0, 6, 1, 0]]
```

must be sorted as

```
[[0, 0, 6, 1, 0]
 [0, 1, 5, 7, 4]
 [1, 0, 4, 2, 3]]
```

So rows must not be changed, only their order. How can I do that?

Comment: It can help? [How to sort 2d array by row in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173797/how-to-sort-2d-array-by-row-in-python/2173873)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how the sorting is done? it's very unclear.

Comment: @magicarm22, no, as far as I can see there is no answer to my question and moreover I talk about numpy and want to use its functions whereas it is lists that are discussed in that topic

Comment: @Guy, well we sort rows by the first column. If values in first column are equal then for such rows we sort them by second column. If in second column values are equal then we look on the third column and so on. It is like lexicographic sort for strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 0, 4, 2, 3],[0, 1, 5, 7, 4],[0, 0, 6, 1, 0]])

np.sort(a.view('i8,i8,i8,i8,i8'), order=['f0'], axis=0).view(np.int)
```

I get

```
array([[0, 0, 6, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 5, 7, 4],
       [1, 0, 4, 2, 3]])
```

`f0` is the column which you want to sort by.

Comment: There is a cooldown for some reason, so I couldn't mark it that way immediately

Answer (score 0):

pythons normal sort already does this.... I wasted 1 hour trying to figure this out as well.

just do result = sorted(original_2d_array)

Comment: Welcome! OP provided input data. Please use it to validate your code.